# Cannot load a custom library in xml layout

Tags: java, android, xml

Iam recently building an android app which will display all attributes of a vehicle which includes a speedometer for displaying the speed of vehicle.i came across various library but every time i try to import the library in my project,it works well, but when i try to include that in xml layout 
**following error**,

The following classes could not be found:

```
- com.sidimi.mucahit.gaugeview.GaugeView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

I searched everywhere for the solution but was unable to solve the problem.
can anyone help me out by telling the exact solution to my problem step by step?

Comment: Whether you can access this class in Java file?

Comment: you must giving the wrong package name....check your package name once

Comment: Did you mentione the library module in settings.gradle ?
Ex: FOr morphing number project, settings.gradle should have ':MorphingNumber'

Comment: Is this Java related  ? Then please add `java` tag !

Comment: You are using eclipse or Studio?

Comment: How do you know importing the library into your project works well? Are you using a Jar, or Maven/Gradle?